# Can not send Multiple choices from select2 with fromdata to upload file

Tags: php, jquery

I have html select2,it can selected multiple option:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-recipient">Recipient:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <span class="input-icon block col-xs-12 no-padding">
            <select name="for" id="for" class="for" multiple="multiple" placeholder="For" style="width: 92%">
            <?php
                foreach($this->forList as $dataFor){ 
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $dataFor['ohp_id'];?>"><?php echo $dataFor['title'];?> Of <?php echo $dataFor['name'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php
                foreach($this->group as $group){ 
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $group['object_group_id'];?>"><?php echo $group['object_group_name'];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user col-xs-0"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".refnd").select2({placeholder: "Reference ND"});
    $(".for").select2({placeholder: "For"});
```

And this jquery:

[image]

But in PHP,it just show 1 option selected. How To fix it?

Comment: Please dont post pictures, Code it text, copy/paste it into your question

Comment: In php the `$_POST['for']` variable will be an array if more than one item in your dropdown is selected, you did realise that right?

Comment: For multiselect option first change the name to array, like `name="for[]"`
Then `if(in_array($your_value,$array)){ echo "selected='selected'"}` Got it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i know, but when i print_r in php it just show one value, i use formdata to send it cause i have upload file.

Comment: The answer is below, just make the `name="for"` into `name="for[]"` on your select, to tell the browser to pass an array rather than just a scalar value for the dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the dropdown name as an array:

```
<select name="for" id="for" class="for" multiple="multiple" placeholder="For" style="width: 92%">

<select name="for[]" id="for" class="for" multiple="multiple" placeholder="For" style="width: 92%">
```

JS:

```
var selectedOpt = $('#for').val();  // it will return an array of selected options
// Now use the selectedOpt array in your ajax call
```